# Projecting a 2D road onto a 3D elevation mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to create a track for [Assetto Corsa](http://www.assettocorsa.net/en/) (a racing game) based on a real mountain road that's close to where I live. It's an ambitious endeavour, but I hope to learn a lot in the process - even if I won't eventaully finish the whole road.

What I've already done is: I imported an SRTM elevation file with this [excellent plugin](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/Import-SRTM-%28.hgt%29) which turns it into a georeferenced mesh. I had to delete big parts of this mesh because it was huge, but now I have the mountain ready.

Next I imported an OSM file containing the road in question with [a plugin](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/Import-OpenStreetMap-(.osm)) written by the same author. Now I have two gereferenced objects which superimpose perfectly from what I can tell.

[image: Perspective view]

*Perspective view with the road floating above the mesh*

The problem is that, while the mesh is 3D and ready to use, the road is a 2D path. What I want is to have a 3D path of the road (with elevation) which I can then use as the basis of the road for the game as explained [in this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPmzhqfw-7I).

[image: Top down view]

*Top down view*

I think I can obtain this path by:

1. Intersecting an extrusion of the 2D road path with the 3D mesh, but how do I do this? I went as far as creating the extrusion, but I don't know how to do the intersection.
2. Using Knife Project to cut the mesh with the road's projection. Again, I tried, but Blender crashes, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that with the shrink wrap modifier as follows :

original mesh

[image]

[image]

Add the shrink wrap modifier :

[image]

and you will get this

[image]

if the road is not curved enough " didnt follow the mountain exactly " try to subdivide it before applying the modifier

Comment: don't use the subsurf modifier use the subdivide tool "w in edit mode" so you don't lose the details of the road

Comment: The Subsurf is the best way to go, you just need to change the method from Catmull-Clark to simple, in-order to retain details.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your answer. But now I hit [another bump](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/array-and-curve-modifiers-behave-strangely?lq=1) in the road. Pun intended. :-)