# Array and curve modifiers behave strangely

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create a road from a plane and a curve which I obtained from converting a mesh. This mesh was at its turn obtained by using the shrink wrap modifier on two meshes. Explained in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24287/projecting-a-2d-road-onto-a-3d-elevation-mesh).

[image]

*This is how the setup looks*

I created a small plane at the lower left side of the path from top view, intended to be replicated along the path to form the road, as explained in [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/gPmzhqfw-7I?t=2m10s).

[image]

*This is how the modifiers for the plane look.*

[image]

*And this is the monstrosity which I get when I select 'Road' as the Curve modifier's object*

What I would like is that the plane would follow the path and create a road over the mountain. I tried playing with the settings of both modifiers but I'm not getting anywhere expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should convert the road mesh into a curve using Alt+C

Comment: Did that, I thought I made it clear in the first paragraph. Without conversion it wouldn't show up in the *Curve* dropdown of the *Array modifier*.

Comment: Try changing the *Deformation Axis* until you get something close to what you want.

Comment: That was my first thought too. Clicked each of them, and I played with the offsets on the *Array modifier*, to no avail. I was only getting this type of fantasy shapes.

Comment: I didn't go through the links you posted so I'm not sure what you've done or not done but one thing that is sure to cause a curve/object/array setup is to have origins at different places.

Comment: make sure the plane and the curve's origins are in the same place

Comment: after you convert the mesh to a curve you should toggle in edit mode before it take effect

Comment: It was an origin issue as many suggested above. I'll be writing an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an origin related issue as suggested in the comments by MarcClintDion and cegaton.

What I did to fix it was:

1. Switched to edit mode with the curve selected;
2. Selected the first vertex of the curve;
3. Snap <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected*;
4. Got out of edit mode;
5. Set Origin <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> >*Origin to 3D Cursor*;
6. Selected the plane;
7. Set Origin <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin 3D Cursor*.

Not sure if steps 6 and 7 are necessary.

Additionally because the generated road was getting crazy cambers in some parts I went to the curve's properties and set *Twisting* to *Z-Up*.